# Creating a Goolge Fusion Table with GeoJSON data

Tags: geojson, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to import a csv file of data into Google Fusion Tables. Included in the data is column of data that contains a polygon for each row which is defined as GeoJSON. All the data imports without issue and I can copy the GeoJSON into [geojsonlint.com](http://geojsonlint.com/) to confirm it's valid.

However, if I select an individual row and click the "geocode..." link under the geometry field it always reports "Geocoding failed".

Is it actually possible to import GeoJSON polygons into Fusion Tables? If so, how is it best to achieve this?

I know KML can be imported and I'm sure I've seen GeoJSON also mentioned, but this was in the API documentation rather than the regular UI documentation.